# Что делать со "средними" вопросами?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

Я увидел странный вопрос: [Отсеивание input с буквами и символами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1502336/)

Непонятно что с ним делать?

- Ставить тревогу насчет учебного задания
- Просто ставить минус
- Или просто его пропустить?

На нем уже -2 голоса и я не знаю что с ним делать.

Comment: Один "чистов" интересуется, что  делать, другой "чистов" ответил на вопрос ))

Comment: Я всегда исходил из правила, как медик - не навреди. Если вы считаете, что вопрос плохой, то ставьте минус, если позволяет репутация, пометьте вопрос к закрытию. Ставить тревоги точно не стоит. Если видите, что вопрос можно "развить", то попросите улучшить вопрос, можете сами отредактировать текст, улучшив его качество. Стоит ли сразу минусовать и закрывать вопрос, если человек не профессионально его сформулировал? Ну не знаю... Я бы дал шанс исправиться

Comment: @SwaD кстати мы братья. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос не средний, а явно низкокачественный.

1. Отсутствует внятная формулировка заголовка "Отсеивание input с буквами и символами" - прочитав такое, какой шанс, что в дальнейшем кто-то сможет найти вопрос по такому заголовку? Иными словами, принесет ли этот вопрос пользу сообществу?
2. Нет никаких примеров кода, чтобы показать, что человеку явно нужно, объяснить свою проблему.
3. Нет собственных попыток, несмотря на то, что задание с большей вероятностью учебное ("На вход подается строка..." - очень похоже на вырезку из условия какой-то задачи)

Тревогу ставить на такие вопросы точно не нужно, сил сообщества достаточно, чтобы решить проблему не привлекая модераторов.

Если репутация позволяет - голосовать за закрытие с пометкой "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.", если не позволяет - просто ставить минус и сообщить об этом в комментариях, чтобы человек знал, в чем он не прав.

Отвечать на такие вопросы тоже не стоит, поскольку вопрос с большей вероятностью будет закрыт, не принесет пользы сообществу, а сам человек в результате получения ответа ничему не научится, так как в виду отсутствия собственных попыток навряд ли захочет разбираться в решении.

Некоторые люди даже минусуют ответы на подобные вопросы, так как считают, что помогать таким людям отвечая на плохо сформулированные вопросы не стоит.